# Chrome Extension Development Issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am facing issue with chrome extension.

What the Extension Does: The extension using the content script; dynamically  inserts a div element in a already existing ui list on the main page dom and attaches an onclick event.

The other div of the same ui list have some mouseover ,mouseout, mousedown events attached to the them.

Issue:
When the extension is enabled;  on hovering on the list there are errors suggesting that the function is undefined also the default click behavious is not working. 
Basically It is not able to resolve the functions which existed on the main page js.

I checked that the content script is not doing  on the other elements of the list.
Can anyone help me this to trace down the exact issue ?

Comment: is it just me or there is no code ??

Comment: I will try to add the code as well but it is for a private project. I will try to create a small replica but till then if you can help with this info.

Comment: This is a https://crbug.com/912069 in Chrome 71. You'll have to assign the attributes inside a [page-level code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879). It's fixed in Chrome 72.

Comment: HI will the code work on the previous versions of chrome? It was working fine earlier for us